# Define end and beginning of regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a list of procedure codes like the following:

```
  procedure_codes = ['038911.B', '32431.1', 'fdsfd.B', '13635.1B', '78935.1b']
```

In python I now want to extract all codes:

- without a leading zero
- where the first characters are digits
- that includes a '.' somewhere
- that have digits following the '.'
- that do not end in either a 'b' or 'B'

To me the most logical approach seemed using a regular expression, so I tried

- ([^0]+)  to not select strings with a leading zero
- (\d+)    to only select strings where the first characters are digits
- (.) to only select strings that includes a '.' somewhere
- (\d?) to only select strings that include a digit after the '.'
- ([^bB]?) to not select strings that end in either a 'b' or 'B'

combined (for each element in the list):

```
  for i in procedure_codes:
      if re.search('[^0]\d+\.\d[^bB]?', i):
          print(i)
```

I would suspect python to only return the code: '32431.1' but instead the return is :

- 32431.1
- 13635.1B
- 78935.1b

And thus it seems like the final negation is just completely ignored

Since I'm completely new to using regular expressions I do not know if I am simply making a syntax error or if I have misunderstood regular expressions completely.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to working @obchardon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your regex with `^` and `$` to match *beginning of line* and *end of line* respectively:

```
^[^0]\d+\.\d[^bB]?$
```

Because without them, it finds `13635.1` group in `13635.1B` and the same with `78935.1b`.

Comment: `^` matches beginning of line, `$` matches end of line